# Set Link Clickable in Java-Android

Tags: java, android-widget, android

I am designing an App, where there is TextView, and based on some check condition, I want to make links / phone numbers in the TextView clickable in Java side. Can I do this, I don't want to make it clickable by default which is done by setting in xml file

```
 android:autoLink="all"
```

What I already tried:
Create regular TextView and don't set autoLink="all",

```
     TextView myView = 
                (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.thisIstheTextView);
       myView .setLinksClickable(true);
```

also tried :

```
     myView .setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

None of the above Java code works, I don't want a predesigned xml TextView with autoLink enabled, I want to change the TextView behavior in Java code based on if () conditions. There is no error in my code, but I am not able to achieve what I want. Can you please share your knowledge. Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380349/html-a-tag-not-working-in-android-textview/9380417#9380417

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 Linkify.addLinks(myView, Linkify.ALL);
```

Fixed the issue.

Comment: Works fine! Thx

Answer (score 14):

Use `setAutoLinkMask (int mask)`.

The possible values that can be combined for `mask` are those defined for the [Linkify](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html#ALL) class.

Comment: Thank you. Although this is equivalent method of  android:autoLink, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry I disagree - it does work. You need to call it before a call to `setText(...)` though, it won't change the links in a `TextView` after it already has text in it. Your question asked about how to change the behaviour of a `TextView` depending on what you wanted to show as clickable / linked items (phone numbers etc) "based on some checked condition". I assumed you would do the check, then set the auto link mask then set the text.

Comment: Use Linkify constant like this textView.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.WEB_URLS);